# Text on geom_col not working, axis working

Tags: r, ggplot2, extrafont

I am attempting to create a ggplot2 plot where I set the font for all text elements, including labels on the bars (geom_col), to "LM Roman 10". One could also use another font like "Calibri". The font for axis labels is displaying correctly as is should be: "LM Roman 10", but the labels on the bars still appear in the default R font despite using extrafont and setting the font for the entire plot.

### Dataset

```
data <- data.frame(
  Year = 2010:2021,
  Value = c(8031, 8554, 8124, 7859, 8026, 8326, 8606, 8184, 8332, 8111, 6764, 6439)
)
```

### Load necessary libraries

```
library(ggplot2)
library(extrafont)
library(scales)
```

### Create the plot

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Year, y = Value, fill = as.factor(Year))) +
  geom_col(fill = "#7f7f7f", width = 0.5) +
  geom_text(aes(label = format(Value, big.mark = '.', scientific = FALSE)),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 3.5, colour = 'black', vjust = -0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 10000), labels = scales::comma_format(big.mark = '.')) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Year", limits = c(2009.5, 2021.5), breaks = seq(2010, 2021, by = 1)) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "Number of Units", title = NULL) +
  theme_bw(base_size = 14, base_family = "LM Roman 10") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.grid = element_blank())
```

### Expected Behavior

The font "LM Roman 10" should be applied to all text elements in the plot, including the text labels above the bars.

### Actual Behavior

Axis labels are correctly displayed in "LM Roman 10", but the text labels above the bars (geom_text) are shown in the default R font.

### Question

How can I ensure that the "LM Roman 10" font is used for all text elements in the plot, including the labels of geom_col?

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reading.
Luckily I found the solution myself.

The trick is, to manipulate the geom_text() with

> geom_text(family = "font")

[image: solution]